# How do you keep QPen pixel width the same when zooming in a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt5

I wrote a quick and nasty program to help me visualise an aspect of a project I'm working on. Although I've been working with Qt since 4.1.1, I've never really had the need to use the QGraphics* module.

When I started playing round with the program, I was working on an old computer running Windows XP and Qt4.7.0 and Visual Studio 2008. I've now just copied the file across to my main computer running Windows 8. I've decided to give Qt5 a shot so I've installed QtCreator with Qt5.0.2.

When I compile the exact same code as I created on the Qt4.7.0/XP machine, I get a vastly different result.

This is what I see on my Qt4.7.0 compilation:

[image: Zoomed-out view from Qt4.7.0/XP compilation]

and this is what I see on my Qt5.0.2 compilation:
[image: Zoomed-out view from Qt5.0.2/Win8x64 compilation]

Clearly there's different behaviour in the drawing of each rectangle's border. Also, if I zoom in using the mouse wheel, the rectangle border width gets bigger in the Qt5 compilation but stays the same(about 1 pixel wide) in the Qt4.7 compilation.

How do I change the code so that behaviour in Qt5 is the same as in Qt4.7?

Here's the full code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QWheelEvent>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QMessageBox>

class ItemData : public QSqlRecord{
public:
    ItemData(QSqlRecord const &rec) : QSqlRecord(rec) {}

    qreal left() const { return value(0).toDouble(); }
    qreal top() const { return value(1).toDouble(); }
    qreal width() const { return value(2).toDouble() - left(); }
    qreal height() const { return value(3).toDouble() - top(); }
    QRectF rect() const { return QRectF(left(), top(), width(), height()); }
    QString barcode() const { return value(4).toString(); }
    QString msaName() const { return value(5).toString(); }
    QString msaDescription() const { return value(6).toString(); }
    QString hsaName() const { return value(7).toString(); }
    QString hsaDescription() const { return value(8).toString(); }
};

class DSAItem : public QGraphicsRectItem{
public:
    DSAItem(ItemData const &data, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0)
        :QGraphicsRectItem(parent) {
            setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
            setRect(data.rect());
            QString tip = "<p><b>%1</b></p><p><b>MLSA</b><br/>%2<br/>%3</p><p><b>HLSA</b><br/>%4<br/>%5</p>";
            setToolTip(tip.arg(data.barcode(), data.msaName(), data.msaDescription(), data.hsaName(), data.hsaDescription()));
            if(data.barcode() == "1010100101" || data.barcode() == "1010100114"){
                colour = QColor(Qt::red);
            } else {
                colour = QColor(Qt::yellow);
            }
            colour.setAlphaF(.5);
            setBrush(QBrush(colour));
    }

    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, QVariant const &value){
        if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedHasChanged){
            QColor c = value.toBool() ? QColor(Qt::green) : colour;
            c.setAlphaF(.5);
            setBrush(QBrush(c));
            update(rect());

        }
        return QGraphicsRectItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }

private:
    QColor colour;
};

class View : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    View(QWidget *parent = 0): QGraphicsView(parent){
        populateScene();
        setScene(&scene);
        rotate(-90);
        scale(1.0, -1.0);
        setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
    }

protected:
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *e){
        setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);

        double scaleFactor = 1.15;
        if (e->delta() > 0){
            scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        } else {
            scale(1 / scaleFactor, 1 / scaleFactor);
        }
    }

private:
    void populateScene(){
        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
        //db credentials here

        QString errorMessage;
        bool ok = db.open();
        if (ok){
            QSqlQuery query(db);
            QString sql = //query string here

            if (query.exec(sql)){
                while(query.next()){
                    scene.addItem(new DSAItem(query.record()));
                }
            } else {
                errorMessage = query.lastError().text();
            }
        } else {
            errorMessage = db.lastError().text();
        }

        if (!errorMessage.isEmpty()){
            QMessageBox::critical(0, "Database Error", errorMessage);
        }
    }

private:
    QGraphicsScene scene;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    View view;
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The best answer is given by rpsml below this one. But for historical reasons I'll leave this one here.**

Setting the width of the pen to zero will make it a "cosmetic" pen with a width of 1.

```
QPen p = pen();
p.setWidth(0)
setPen(p);
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried but no, the pen width scales along with the items in Qt5 but not in Qt4.7

Comment: The docs for QPen::setWidth() say "A line width of zero indicates a cosmetic pen. This means that the pen width is always drawn one pixel wide, independent of the transformation set on the painter." have you tried setting the width to 0?

Comment: That's it!!! Thanks Cory. The default value must have changed between versions. Create an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! This is my answer. Click on the triangle pointing up. It is to the left of the text "Have you tried..."

Comment: Ok, but I'll edit the main answer to `setWidth(0)` since that's the one that works

Comment: `p.setCosmetic(true)` is not working for tooltips properly. But this is working.

Answer (score 33):

This is a bit late but might be helpful.

The proposed solution works fine, but limits the pen widht. An alternative is to use the instruction

```
p.setCosmetic(true);
```

According to the Qt reference (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpen.html#isCosmetic)

> Cosmetic pens are used to draw strokes that have a constant width regardless of any transformations applied to the QPainter they are used with.

And it also explains why setting the width to zero works:

> A zero width pen is cosmetic by default; pens with a non-zero width are non-cosmetic.

Comment: I like this information - it is clean (cleaner than the accepted solution) and offers more flexibility

Comment: The last half sentence is quite ambiguous: "A zero width pen is cosmetic by default; pens with a non-zero width are non-cosmetic.". If you only read the last half "pens with a non-zero width are non-cosmetic." then a non-zero pen width should NOT be cosmetic, no matter what you set in `setCosmetic`. That is indeed the behavior I see when testing (PyQt4.7)