# Can I resize QGraphicsItem without creating a class that inherits QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I want to ask a question about can I resize QGraphicsItem without creating a class that inherits QGraphicsItem. For example, something like this:

```
void MyScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
   point = event->scenePos();
   if( ArrowCursor )
   {
      curItem = this->itemAt( point, view->transform() );
      if( curItem && !curItem->isSelected() )
      {
         curItem->update( 10,10, 100, 100 );
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: As the docs state for update: "Schedules a redraw of the area covered by rect in this item. You can call this function whenever your item needs to be redrawn, such as if it changes appearance or size." So it's certainly not going to do it by calling update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curItem->setTransform(QTransform::fromScale(2.0,2.0), true);
```

**Offtopic:** This is strange that you are doing this by subclassing `QGraphicsScene`.

Comment: Thx, I tried it and all is nice and smooth. Well I'm beginner in this thing, so I subclassed QGraphicsScene to get scene coords of cursor with scenePos

Comment: But one thing this method scales thickness of line, how do I escape that?

Comment: @user3130843 : To avoid scaling of the line thickness, use `setCosmetic(true)` for the pen. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075623/how-do-you-keep-qpen-pixel-width-the-same-when-zooming-in-a-qgraphicsview/23174260#23174260

Comment: Why do coords change every time I rescale it, I mean the new item coords, doesn't match top left coords of old item?